# Two-level list has wrong alignment

Tags: lists, alignment

I'm writing my PhD thesis with LaTeX. It's in French, but I think the code will be readable by anyone. I have a list in a list at some point ("enumerate" inside of a "description" one) and I don't understand why my "enumerate" points aren't aligned with each other.

```
\begin{description}
    \item[- Littératie émergente :]
    \item[ ]
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \textbf{Savoirs conceptuels} : connaissances à propos des actes de lecture et d’écriture, connaissance des fonctions de la littéracie, perception de son propre apprentissage de la lecture, littéracie émergente en contexte (raconter une histoire, déchiffrer des panneaux publicitaires/logos, etc.), etc.
        \item \textbf{Savoirs procéduraux} : orthographe préconventionnelle dans une variété de situations, connaissance du nom des lettres, connaissance de la correspondance graphophonologique, lecture de mots (avec aide), etc.
    \end{enumerate}
    \item[- Compétences langagières à l’oral :] compétences narratives, vocabulaire, compréhension à l’oral, etc.
    \item[- Compétences métalinguistiques :] conscience phonologique, syntaxique, etc.\bigskip
  \end{description}
```

Here is a screenshot of the .pdf result :

[image: the "2. Savoir procéduraux" is not aligned with "1. Savoirs conceptuels" (nor with any other bullet point).]

Does anyone see what could be the issue, and/or has a solution for me ?

Many thanks ! :)

Edit :
I have these packages, so I think enumitem is the only one who could be responsible for the mishap...?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{eurosym}% pour le symbole EURO
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{natbib} %Nouvelles biblios
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{loi}{Textes officiels}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true}
\usepackage{setspace} %Gestion des interlignes
\usepackage{xcolor} %Gestion des couleurs
\usepackage{hyperref} %Gestion des URL
\usepackage{graphicx} %Gestion des images
\usepackage{longtable} %Grands tableaux
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\usepackage{tablefootnote} %nbp dans tableaux
\usepackage{amssymb} %symboles pour test maternelle
\usepackage{tipa} %API
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
```

Comment: Off-topic: If you load the `babel` package with the option `french`, you needn't remember to insert a space before `:` symbols, and (if you use an `itemize` environment) you'll get the 'right', i.e., French-typographic symbols in the itemize list.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I'm not sure I remember why I have the "\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true}" line after the babel french package, nor what it's doing, but indeed I have just noticed that I don't need to insert a space after the brackets. I think my (old, french, VIP) supervisor has an opinion on the use of bullet/dash in lists but I can't remember what his opinion is. I'll have to take care of that after I'm done writing the thesis content.

Comment: Also off-topic: the `geometry`-package options `top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=3cm` may be expressed more succinctly as `margin=3cm`; don't load packages more than once (see `hyperref`); the instruction `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is the default nowadays and needn't be issued.

Comment: Thank you so much @Mico ! I'm really learning LaTeX along the way and sometimes reading up old documentation: one of my friends warned me to check up the dates of forum posts before applying blindly what I see LOL

Answer (score 3):

I think an `itemize` environment would be better suited than a `description`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Littératie émergente :}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \textbf{Savoirs conceptuels} : connaissances à propos des actes de lecture et d’écriture, connaissance des fonctions de la littéracie, perception de son propre apprentissage de la lecture, littéracie émergente en contexte (raconter une histoire, déchiffrer des panneaux publicitaires/logos, etc.), etc.
        \item \textbf{Savoirs procéduraux} : orthographe préconventionnelle dans une variété de situations, connaissance du nom des lettres, connaissance de la correspondance graphophonologique, lecture de mots (avec aide), etc.
    \end{enumerate}
    \item \textbf{Compétences langagières à l’oral :} compétences narratives, vocabulaire, compréhension à l’oral, etc.
    \item \textbf{Compétences métalinguistiques :} conscience phonologique, syntaxique, etc.\bigskip
  \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (the bullets could easily be changed to `-`, but we would need to see a small, but compilable text file from you so that we know if you use any packages which influence lists)

Comment: The bullet symbols will get change to `-` symbols automatically if the `babel` package is loaded with the option `french`. :-)

Comment: @Mico Let's hope they are using babel :)

Comment: I am, and thank you, changing it from description to itemize worked ! :-) I don't know why I used a description in the first place, to be fair I am very novice with LaTeX :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `description` add `\mbox{}` after the `\item[...]` command and remove the `\item[]` line.

I restructured a bit your preamble, removing duplicates call and placing `hyperref` where it belongs (at the end).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib} %Nouvelles biblios
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{eurosym}% pour le symbole EURO
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{multibib}
\usepackage{setspace} %Gestion des interlignes
\usepackage{xcolor} %Gestion des couleurs
\usepackage{graphicx} %Gestion des images
\usepackage{longtable} %Grands tableaux
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{tablefootnote} %nbp dans tableaux
\usepackage{amssymb} %symboles pour test maternelle
\usepackage{tipa} %API
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref} %Gestion des URL

\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\newcites{loi}{Textes officiels}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
    \item[- Littératie émergente :] \mbox{}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \textbf{Savoirs conceptuels} : connaissances à propos des actes de lecture et d’écriture, connaissance des fonctions de la littéracie, perception de son propre apprentissage de la lecture, littéracie émergente en contexte (raconter une histoire, déchiffrer des panneaux publicitaires/logos, etc.), etc.
        \item \textbf{Savoirs procéduraux} : orthographe préconventionnelle dans une variété de situations, connaissance du nom des lettres, connaissance de la correspondance graphophonologique, lecture de mots (avec aide), etc.
    \end{enumerate}
    \item[- Compétences langagières à l’oral :] compétences narratives, vocabulaire, compréhension à l’oral, etc.
    \item[- Compétences métalinguistiques :] conscience phonologique, syntaxique, etc.\bigskip
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ooo thank you!!
I've been calling new packages along the way while I've discovered needs for it, this file is five years old ... so i'm so glad you've helped me clean it up. I didn't know the mbox command, and I will use it instead of using ~ everywhere for nbspaces LOL. Many thanks ! :)